# interface/abstract class

Tags: java

i have read some lines from somewhere but i cant understand the meaning of this line clearly .. i dont know why i cant understand. I know the difference between this two very well.. But plz help me .. and explain that what it does mean... ?

> **In design, you want the base class to present only an interface for its
>   derived classes. This means, you don’t
>   want anyone to actually instantiate an
>   object of the base class. You only
>   want to upcast to it (implicit
>   upcasting, which gives you polymorphic
>   behaviour), so that its interface can
>   be used. This is accomplished by
>   making that class abstract using the
>   abstract keyword. If anyone tries to
>   make an object of an abstract class,
>   the compiler prevents it.**

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Where is a source of this sentence?

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class Animal {
  public abstract String speak();
}
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public String speak() { return "woof!"; }
}
public class Duck extends Animal {
  public String speak() { return "quack!"; }
}

Animal a = Zoo.getRandomAnimal();
a.speak();
```

You want people to refer to animals as Animal, rather than specifically Dog or Duck. That way, if you breed a dog/duck hybrid, and thus a new type of animal is created, they don't have to go around changing code to deal with this new wonder.

The interface they are speaking about in your quote is not talking about a Java 'interface' but rather 'a collection of methods you may use to interact with this object'.

All animals speak, and that's what important. It's the interface. Exactly how they speak is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is pure abstract class which doesn't have concrete methods while abstract class  having concrete methods and abstract methods also

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you define class A as abstract, you cannot create an instance of type A. You can only create instances of A's subclasses (classes that extend/inherit from A).